# Learning German language online

Tags: online-learning, german

I have recently finished B1 online course from Goethe Institut. Now I can not continue B2 course at Goethe Institut for some reasons but I want to continue learning online. I would like to ask for resources to learn the German language online. I have tried Duolingo, Seedlang, Babbel, Memrise and other apps like these - I think they are just for fun and not a good fit for learning a language.
How can I learn the German language online? Is there an online course?

Update:
I have tried Duolingo. I think it is not effective because it is mostly grammar oriented. It does not provide a systematic approach - it is just random tests. I have a feeling that apps like that are built not for helping in learning a language but showing more ads. I think the interactive way of learning a language with speaking, listening, writing, reading tasks is more interesting and effective than solving tests in Duolingo.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question.

Comment: smarterGerman is pretty good, and he has a B2 mastery course. You could also work through FSI German.

Comment: @AML thank you for the suggestion. I will try it.

Comment: I have given a more thorough answer below with more options for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several recommendations:

1. SmarterGerman has a [B2-level course](https://courses.smartergerman.com/p/learn-german-online-course-b2-part-01-of-08). I have worked on the B1 course before, and it is solid.
2. Deutsche Welle (DW) has both [B2 and C-level courses](https://www.dw.com/en/learn-german/german-courses/s-2547) for your enjoyment.
3. [Assimil](https://www.assimil.com/en/with-ease/1448-german-9782700508291.html) claims their book/audio goes up to B2 level. I have used this book and enjoyed it. Not sure it's really B2 level, but it's a matter of opinion. Certainly at least b1.
4. [L2 Press](https://www.l2press.com/german) offers a book of short stories that are a solid intermediate level. I have also used it, and I really like it. If you like reading stories with audio, then this is for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have completed B1 at Goethe as well and waiting for the next B2 schedule. I do not mean to discourage you but just wanted to let you know the facts - B1 and B2 are mid level courses (C1, C2 are advanced and close to native speaker). Given that perspective, B2 is "*supposed to be*" difficult.

I have got feedback from various learners that online is simply not possible and definitely not recommended for any course beyond B1. So I highly recommend that you pursue your journey in classroom way to achieve good learning experience.

In my opinion, the beginner levels (A1,A2) can be done online.

Hope this helps.